# Switching to Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: system-installation, windows, gparted, format, removing

I've been using Ubuntu for a while now. I still have windows installed and it's taking up the majority of my hard drive space. I want to fully switch to Ubuntu though. I've backed up everything I need from Windows and I'm ready to get rid of it. I just don't know how to do it. Here is a Screenshot from gParted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using gparted you should be able to select the ntfs partitions you want to delete and delete them - Once deleted you have to format the unpartitioned space into ext4 or fat32 (again using gparted) - If you dont want to completely remove windows you can shrink the windows partition down using `diskmgmt.msc` from windows

If you decide to completely remove Windows via gparted as described you will have to either 1) flag your sda5 partition as boot or 2) create a new partition for /boot and and move the files from its current location to the new /boot partition. Also you will want to remove windows from the grub menu -

A tool that I use to 'fix' my grub boot loader is (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) - I have this installed on a usb that i keep in my toolbox

If you want to manually do this:

Make a bootable disk for Gparted - (http://gparted.org/livecd.php)
I use this to make bootable usb's - (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - however you want will be good bud.

Gparted can be used to make a boot partition (mine is formatted ext2 but i dont think theres any issue with making it all ext4) - minimum size of this partition is 200 mb (you dont want it to be too big at all) and you will want to flag it as /boot.

Some examples for you: (Things are named aptly so you can logically see the process)

```
/dev/sda2 - 200 MB new boot partition
/dev/sda1 - 50 GB existing linux partition
```

Make mount points.

```
mkdir /mnt/newboot /mnt/existing
```

Mount the partitions:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/newboot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/existing
```

Copy /boot files:

```
cp -a /mnt/existing/boot/* /mnt/newboot/
```

Unmount the boot partition from /mnt and remount to /boot:

```
umount /dev/sda2
mount /dev/sda2 /newboot
```

To remove windows from Grub:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You can (put a #) in front of each line to "comment out" the entries pertaining to Microsoft Windows - or if you are comfy with just deleting them - so be it.  I usually make a copy of any conf file i mess with and save it in my home dir just in case i screw something up.

Comment: This answer may benefit from a word on Grub and the boot partition.